# changing culture changes numbers to native mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

i am using cultures to changing language and direction in my web application,
problem when i'm using en-US it works fine but when i'm changing to fa-IR it shows an error for my strings and numbers :

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +10725831
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +145
   System.Int32.Parse(String s) +23
   PortalCore.Admin.Stat.SetValues() in f:\Projects\10-14-2013 PortalCore\EasyToUsePortal\PortalCore\Admin\Stat.aspx.cs:87
   PortalCore.Admin.Stat.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\Projects\10-14-2013 PortalCore\EasyToUsePortal\PortalCore\Admin\Stat.aspx.cs:22
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

or

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
[FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
   System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style) +3369666
   System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider) +31
   PortalCore.Admin.ManageTasks.btnSubmitTask_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\Projects\10-14-2013 PortalCore\EasyToUsePortal\PortalCore\Admin\ManageTasks.aspx.cs:28
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9552602
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

i think my numbers are changing to native mode for example :

0 ==> .

can u help me please? i don't want to change numbers.

Comment: We can't see your code so we can't help with what is wrong...